# How can I create functions on the fly and make them use different parameters based on a params attribute of a class?

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have the following classes:

```
    class _params():
        def __init__(self,params):
            for param in params:
                pname = param[0]
                pvalue = param[1:]
                if not isinstance(pvalue,(list,tuple)):
                    pvalue = [pvalue]
                for param_value in pvalue:
                    _params.__setattr__(self,f'{pname}_{param_value}',param_value)
    
    class ClassParams():
        def __init__(self,_class):
            params = getattr(_class,'params',[])
            names = getattr(_class,'names',[])
            if params:
                _class.p = _class.params = _params(params)
                for param in params:
                    param_key = param[0]
                    param_values = param[1:]
                    if not isinstance(param_values,(list,tuple)):
                        param_values = [param_values]
                    for param_value in param_values:
                        setattr(_class,f'{param_key}_{param_value}',getattr(_class,param_key))
    
    class strat():
        params = (('sma',15,16),)
        
        def sma(self):
            print(f"I'm of length {self.p.sma_15}")
    
    class dummy():
        def addparams(self,p):
            self.abc = p()
            ClassParams(self.abc)
    
    dum = dummy()
    dum.addparams(strat)
```

The class `strat` holds the parameters of the function `sma` in a `tuple`, so what I'm trying to achieve is to create a function for each parameter in the `tuple` of `params`.

After executing the code above, if I run the sma functions created, they both print `I'm of length 15`

```
        dum.abc.sma_15()
      >>I'm of length 15
    
        dum.abc.sma_16()
      >>I'm of length 15
```

How can I make `dum.abc.sma_16()` print `I'm of length 16`?